# Where can I find questions about celebrations and happenings?

Tags: discussion, lists

I have seen some questions that had to with different celebrations and happenings. Where can I find such posts?

Comment: Well, if such posts are common enough and wanted by people, we could add a specific tag to them. Then they can be easily found.

Comment: @MartinScharrer What would be an appropriate tag name?

Comment: You can find some at {[tag:fun]}. Generally, I don't think a tag for that would be appropriate, since it would be a meta-tag, which are deprecated. A list in a meta-question seems fine.

Comment: @doncherry Yes, I it might be too meta for a tag. Also it'd be hard to name it properly. I made the answer community wiki so that it will be easier for anyone to contribute to the list.

Comment: Maybe `{event}`. I think there is a low risk of misuse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some (please help to keep it updated).

## Holidays

### Xmas

- [How can we draw a Christmas tree with decorations, using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz)
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39200/how-can-we-draw-a-sophisticated-christmas-tree-with-the-power-of-pstricks

### New Year

- [How do you say Happy New Year with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7869/how-do-you-say-happy-new-year-with-latex)
- [How can we display fireworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39485/how-can-we-draw-fireworks-effects-using-tikz)

## Happenings

- [Contest: Show Off Your Skillz in TeX & Friends [TeX.sx birthday]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34482/contest-show-off-your-skillz-in-tex-friends-tex-sx-birthday)
- [How can I draw a cake using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42598/how-can-i-draw-a-cake-using-tikz)